# FastApi: endpoint returns 422 while I don't have any parameters to pass

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, fastapi

the endpoint get_my_user returns 422 Error: Unprocessable Entity, check the error below, I am not passing an id in the parameters, however I noticed when I change it to post request it works. I don't know what Id the error is talking about, get_current_user works fine with other endpoints :

```
{
  "detail": [
    {
      "loc": [
        "path",
        "id"
      ],
      "msg": "value is not a valid integer",
      "type": "type_error.integer"
    }
  ]
}
```

```
def get_user_data(user_id: int, db: Session):
    user = db.query(models.User, models.Role).join(
        models.UserRole, models.UserRole.user_id == models.User.id).join(
        models.Role, models.Role.id == models.UserRole.role_id).filter(models.User.id == user_id).first()
    
    if not user:
        return None
    
    return schemas.UserOut(
        **user._data[0].__dict__,
        role=user._data[1].__dict__,
        message=f"User with id {user_id}",
        status_code=status.HTTP_200_OK
    )

@router.get('/me', response_model=schemas.UserOut, status_code=status.HTTP_200_OK)
def get_my_user(db: Session = Depends(get_db), current_user=Depends(oauth2.get_current_user)):
    user_data = get_user_data(current_user.id, db)
    if not user_data:
        return schemas.UserOut(
            message="User does not exist",
            status_code=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND
        )
    return user_data
```

I am expecting to return the user data,

Comment: What is the actual call? Do you have e.g. a curl statement to show the call?

Comment: I am calling it from swagger docs. does that answer your question?

Comment: Show the code of `oauth2.get_current_user`

Comment: Also, if user not found you should return `HTTPException` instead of `schemas.UserOut`

Comment: It'd have to be `@router.get('/{id}')`, since the `id` part is matching the `me` part. Make sure you register the `/me` handler before the `/{id}` handler.